# Удаление из списка всех элементов, которые в себе имеют меньше четырех знаков

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Например :

`lst = ['1234','2341','123']`

А должно стать:

```
lst = ['1234', '2341']
```

'123' - не подошло потому что там меньше четырех знаков

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lst = ['1234', '2341', '123']
lst = [item for item in lst if len(item) >= 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 4, lst)
```